# benchmarking ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, benchmarking

I have just installed Ruby Enterprise Edition and would like to run some benchmarking tests against my system Ruby. Are there canonical benchmark tests I should implement?

Answer (score 3):

The most interesting and in-depth [Ruby benchmarks](http://antoniocangiano.com/category/ruby-benchmark-suite/) I have seen anyone do is the series of blog posts by Antonio Cangiano.